# Object array's object properties changing when returning array

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have a function that has been made to manipulate and create an object array and add a `position` key to each item within the array, but it seems to not be working properly at all...

**My function:**

```
var fillQueue = function(choices, currentQueue) {
  var choice, i, positionInQueue, previousTitle, resultQueue;

  resultQueue = [];
  previousTitle = "";

  i = 0;

  while (i < 10) {
    positionInQueue = i + 1;
    console.log('Adding song to position ' + positionInQueue);

    if (currentQueue[i]) {
      previousTitle = currentQueue[i].title;
      currentQueue[i].position = positionInQueue;
      resultQueue.push(currentQueue[i]);
    } else {
      choice = choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length)];

      if (choice.title !== previousTitle) {
        previousTitle = choice.title;
        choice.position = positionInQueue;
        resultQueue.push(choice);
      } else {
        choice = choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length)];
        previousTitle = choice.title;
        choice.position = positionInQueue;
        resultQueue.push(choice);
      }
    }

    i++;
  }

  return resultQueue;
};
```

If this is called correctly, substituting in values for `choices` and `currentQueue` (`currentQueue` can also be an empty array) like below, the function returns an array, which is intended, but screws around with the `position` keys on each object within it for some reason.

```
var test = fillQueue([ {title: '1'}, {title: '2'}, {title: '3'}, {title: '4'} ], [ { title: '5', position: 1 } ]);
```

The above variable will contain this:

```
[ { title: '5', position: 1 },
  { title: '1', position: 9 },
  { title: '3', position: 7 },
  { title: '1', position: 9 },
  { title: '2', position: 10 },
  { title: '2', position: 10 },
  { title: '3', position: 7 },
  { title: '1', position: 9 },
  { title: '1', position: 9 },
  { title: '2', position: 10 } ]
```

As you can see, it's not adding the `position`s correctly into each object. Each object within the returned array should have a `position` of `i + 1`, but instead it seems to be some random number from 1 to 10 - some of the objects even have the same `position`.

**I have tried:**

- Renaming `position` to something else, in case it was something that was already being used by JavaScript
- Making sure that the correct `position` is being added to the object before and after `.push`ing it into the array.

This is making me really confused. Your help would be appreciated.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/deansheather/jnw8jdf4/

Comment: what is the output format you need exactly?

Comment: What you are pushing into the array is a **reference** to a *choice*, so each time you update `choice.position`, all instances of that choice get the same "position" value, e.g. all the choices with "Title:1" will have the same position because they all reference the same object. You need to create a copy of the choice, update its position and push the copy into the array.

Comment: @TajAhmed I am looking for an array containing 10 objects. Each object in this array **must** have a `position` property equal to `i + 1`.

Comment: @RobG How do I fix this then and change it from a reference into it's own separate variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pushing references into the array, so each time you update *choice.position* all references to the same choice in the array get the same position value.

To fix that, copy the *choice* object, update its position and push that into the array, e.g.

```
if (choice.title !== previousTitle) {
        previousTitle = choice.title;
        newChoice = objCopyShallow(choice); // see below for copy function
        newChoice.position = positionInQueue;
        resultQueue.push(newChoice);
}
```

For this application, a simple copy function is:

```
function objCopyShallow(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(acc, v) {
      acc[v] = obj[v];
      return acc;
    },{});
}
```

There are a million questions and answers here about "how to copy an object" if you want something deeper.

Answer (score 1):

As RobG Already said you are pushing references to your array.So create a copy of your choice object and then push to your array. create a copy of your object using `clone()` 
change your assignment to
`choice = clone(choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length)]);`
you are done.

```
function clone(obj) {
    if (null == obj || "object" != typeof obj) return obj;
    var copy = obj.constructor();
    for (var attr in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(attr)) copy[attr] = obj[attr];
    }
    return copy;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to come up with the following.  This works as I'm avoiding using for/while loops which have reference "gotchas" in JS you need to be aware of when updating values using it.

```js
var fillQueue = function(choices, currentQueue) {
  // concat choices to end of currentQueue
  // create a new array instance with updated position property using .map
  // keep 10 elements from new array starting at index 0 
  return currentQueue.concat(choices).map( (e, i) => {
    return Object.assign({title:e.title, position:i+1});
  }).splice(0, 10)
};
```

Comment: This has the same issues as the OP.